# Adjusting Dijkstra for transit routing — minimize route changes

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

I am working on a small project that involves finding the best route on a bus system. I build a graph where the stops are vertices and the edges are weighted with the time between stops.

I though I would try to use a variant of Dijkstra to find the best route. When finding the next edges to consider, the algorithm only looks at edges whose departure time as after the current time along the trip. There are several parts of the graph where buses arrive and depart the same series of series of stops simultaneously. To prevent needlessly switching buses, I add a cost to route changes when selecting the best edge. This has worked surprisingly well and is quite fast.

The snag I've hit is on choosing the first bus. Consider the following  scenario:

[image]

Dijkstra will favor taking bus A because it arrives at stop 2 first. If you're going to stop 2 that's great. But if you're going to stop 3, Bus B is a better choice and the total cost for both are identical. I don't think I can avoid the greedy nature of Dijkstra, but it's working so well for everything else, I don't want to discard it if I don't need to.

Does any know a good solution that can address the issue of correctly picking the first stop (or maybe adjusting it after the fact?). Alternatively is there a better algorithm that people use for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use plain Dijkstra's on a larger graph constructed as follows:

- Nodes are described by triples `(L, T, B)`. Every time a bus `B` arrives or departs from location `L` at time `T`, create a node `(L, T, B)`.
- Create a directed edge for every bus route segment. That is, if bus `B` departs from location `L1` at time `T1` and arrives at location `L2` at time `T2`, add the edge `(L1, T1, B) -> (L2, T2, B)`, with cost `T2 - T1` (or any other reasonable cost, maybe depending on the fare).
- Add edges corresponding to "staying on the bus at a stop". If bus `B` arrives at a location `L` at time `T1` and later departs from the same location at time `T2`, add the edge `(L, T1, B) -> (L, T2, B)` with cost `T2 - T1`.
- Add edges corresponding to "switching buses". Add a directed edge from `N1 = (L, T1, B1)` to `N2 = (L, T2, B2)` with cost `T2 - T1 + epsilon` if the following is true:

  - `N1` is an "arrival" node (bus `B1` arrives at `L` at time `T1`)
  - `N2` is a "departure" node (bus `B2` departs from `L` at time `T2`)
  - `T1 < T2` and `B1 != B2`

In this graph, the cost of a path is the total time plus `c * epsilon` where `c` is the number of bus changes. `epsilon` represents the "cost" of switching buses. For instance, if someone equally prefers "stay on the bus" and "switch buses but save 2 minutes", then `epsilon` should be 2 minutes.

You can also add a "minimum switching time" `S` by modifying the inequality `T1 < T2` to `T1 + S < T2`. This will exclude edges where `T1` and `T2` are so close that someone can't reasonably switch buses in time.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need to add the cost of transfer to your graph.

First thing that comes to my mind,  probably not a best solution is to add extra nodes around your stops.  So instead of StopB you would have

Stop-B get off Bus-A
Stop-B 
Stop-B get on Bus-B

You would have to do it to all the buses on for each stop.

Probably there are better options.  This is first thing I could come up with in 2 minutes.

Comment: I agree with Vlad. But instead of adding nodes, modify your cost function to be contextual.

Comment: @Vincent The cost function can't be contextual if the nodes don't store information about which bus was taken to get there.

Comment: Ah .. right. Building another graph with added nodes representing the context seems to be unavoidable then.

Comment: @Vincent.  You might get away with same number of nodes,  but more edges.  As you pointed out function cannot be contextual so it boils down where you going to store that context.

Answer (score 1):

Another proposal

Instead of adding nodes.  You can just more edges.  Instead of representing bus route (A -> B -> C) as you represent it as follows:

A -> B

A -> C

B -> C

For each edge you add to the cost time that takes to get on the bus and get off the bus.

Answer (score 1):

The answers have been really helpful. I ended up doing something a little different, but inspired by the ideas here. Basically each stop has 'exits' assigned to each bus route with edges leading out of the stop. In order for bus `A` to reach Stop 3 it needs to enter Stop 2 and then take the 'B' exit. The edges entering the station incur an extra cost. Buses can bypass the station for free if the routes match. So bus 'B' never needs to enter Stop 2 to go to Stop 3, but bus A does.

This allows either bus to be the shortest route to Stop 2 and allows both buses to reach Stop 3. But if you are going to Stop 3 from Stop 1, starting on bus B will most be the cheapest route because it doesn't need to go through the station and incur the extra cost.

[image]