# Dijkstra's algorithm for bus route (prioritise on fare price)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am struggling with a Dijkstra's algorithm problem with two costs: time and fare price. Assume there are flat ticket rate for each bus route(could differ between different routes) and between two consecutive bus stops, every bus takes the same time to travel. I am wondering if there's an algorithm might be suited to this problem? It needs to be polynomial time in regards to total bus line counts n, k instances and p stops. The bus timetables are made of tuples (bus stop, time arrives, and potentially time it departs(doesn't matter too much)).

I forgot to mention that since I only need to arrive the place on time(to say arrive the office just before the time to commence my work), I could probably just filter the ones within the timeframe...

Sorry for the vague post anyways.

I am thinking of DFS but DFS is just not effective... Any better ways?

Comment: You need to clarify for yourself what you are optimizing for: time or price. Do you prefer a longer route that is cheaper, or a shorter route that is more expensive?

Comment: Determine the trade-off.  TotalValue = x * time + y * cost

Comment: @Thomas cheaper routes are better! Actually I only need to arrive in time so I could get rid of other routes for which the timetable does not fit. And just prioritise on the price. Maybe I should modify my question. Do you have any suggestions on this one now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient vehicle routing for transfer of packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648824/efficient-vehicle-routing-for-transfer-of-packages)

Comment: This does look a bit different... I'm looking for an algorithm(in theory). Probably this is closer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204824/adjusting-dijkstra-for-transit-routing-minimize-route-changes

Comment: If you want to solve this problem with Dijkstra's, then you need to operate on an implicit graph.  Find the lowest cost route through all reachable (stop,time) combinations, for example.  You can optimize somewhat by eliminating combinations that aren't Pareto optimal.  I've written a lot of implicit graph answers recently, so maybe someone else wants to expand?

Answer (score 0):

"Time is money!"

How much does time cost?  Determine that and you have your answer.

If you are willing to pay $1 to arrive 1 min faster, then you set the cost of each edge as the sum of the cost in dollars and the time in minutes.

I general, any optimization is done by minimizing or maximizing a function of all the different factors.  The function is usually and most simply a linear function, but optimizing algorithms such as Dijkstra will work on any sort of defined single valued function.

```
min| max f( f1, f2,...)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is sometimes no exchange rate that works.  If the goal is to find the cheapest price within 1 hour, and the costs of available routes are (1.5,0), (1,1), (0,1.5), for example, then there is no weighted-sum cost function that will select the correct route with cost (1,1).

Comment: Fortune has nothing to with it.  The OP has changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I understand that you are optimizing for price, with a constraint on time.

Each node in your graph will be a tuple `(stop, time)`, and each edge will be a possible connection that can be made from that stop starting at that time. The weight of the edge will be the price, because that's what you want to minimize.

Just run Dijstra over that graph as normal, but immediately discard any nodes whose `time` exceeds the maximum arrival time. The result will be the lowest-cost itinerary that arrives on time.